# Webmaster Tools Error: We weren't able to add x@x.com. Please try again later

Tags: google-search-console, error

I've been trying to add additional owners to a Google Webmaster Tools account, but receiving this error message:

[image]

> We weren't able to add x@x.com. Please try again later.

Has anyone come across this before or discovered a solution?

Answer (score 2):

From a bit of trial-and-error, it appears that Google limits you to adding approximately 3 owners per hour.  I waited 1-2 hours and it allowed me to add an additional 2-3.

Hope that helps others facing this vague error message.

Comment: I am glad you found a solution. And Thank You for sharing the solution here. Cheers!!